# Concatenation of the strings vector in Clojure

Tags: string, vector, clojure

I would like to concatenate strings stored in a vector. For example if I have `["a" "b" "c"]` in the vector I would like to get as a result `"abc"`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [clojure.string join](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.string/join) function for that

```
(clojure.string/join ["a" "b" "c"])
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this using `map`?

Comment: You can use reduce here: (reduce str ["a" "b" "c"]) but I'd better use join function.

Comment: If you don't need the separator of clojure.string/join, apply str is the better solution.

Comment: @NielsK Why is `str` a better solution when no separator is required? I arrived here looking for the answer to that question. :-)

Comment: 1 - str is in core, so no need for extra namespaces to be loaded. 2 - In `join` without seperator there's a superfluous call for (.append sb "") per item in coll, which isn't done in `str`.

Comment: While this may seem trivial, there's large performance gains to be had. Instead of calling `str` left and right during construction of very large strings, building a large collection and calling `(apply str coll)` (or even `(apply str (flatten coll))`) only once makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 35):

You can use `apply` with the `str` function:

```
(apply str ["a" "b" "c"])
```

Comment: (apply str <sequence>) is the approach you will see used most often (as NielsK says, as long as you don't need the separator)

Comment: If you do want delimited you can use `interpose` thusly  `(apply str (interpose "," ["a" "b" "c"]))  => "a,b,c"`

Comment: If you only want to use delimiters for use in the final string, better use `clojure.string/join`, instead of `apply str` combined with `interpose`. The latter uses a lot more allocations. If you want to alter the collection some more before turning it into a string, `interpose` is the way to go though.

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the ways Clojure's reduce can be used. Note the session at Clojure's REPL:

```
[dsm@localhost:~]$ clj
Clojure 1.4.0
user=> (reduce str ["a" "b" "c"])
"abc"
user=>
```

Comment: Any advantage over `apply str`?

Comment: No advantages, only disadvantages since every iteration of reduce will create another Stringbuilder, which is computationally more expensive per extra item in a collection.

Comment: Yeah, but, unlike `apply`, it will work with functions which take a fixed number of arguments